# is it possible to see verbose of downloaded application of google play store?

Tags: android, debugging, google-play, verbose

I want to see the Error of my uploaded application on google play store.It is having some issues and i want to debug that issue. Is it possible to debug that issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only see it if the apk is debuggable

Comment: Yes you can see Verbose just connect your device to the system and in Android Studio you can see the Log Trace

Comment: select `No Filter` you can see all of your device's log

Comment: @VivekMishra nonsense. You see logs of apps that emits logs.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sorry I removed that but I read somewhere like that earlier

Comment: @VivekMishra you may have proguard running for release mode with rules stripping `Log.*`, but if you do not have, then your release will be emiting to logcat normally.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski after your previous comment I read about it and understands that if logs are written in release apk that can be seen

Answer (score 0):

You have To implement [HockeyApp SDK](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk) this service allow you to track all crashes that happens to your application wherever it was on any device. 
And when you want to deploy your app to play store you should set  the attribute debbugable="false" in your `<application>` tag in your manifest so nobody can trak your application logs.

Comment: @Hider there is no crash. i just want to see the logs of deploy application on google play store.

Comment: @SundeepBadhotiya press on the link and read what this SDK can do, it has a feedback manager and you have to implement it to your code its not difficult they provide sample code, there is no straight way to achieve what are you trying to do and this is the proper way since this SDK is for reporting about everything and you can use it as you want.

Comment: @SundeepBadhotiya if this is not the answer for you so why did you down voted it?
I will flag your question

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your Manifest `android:debuggable="true"`  inside the `<application>` tag. by default `android:debuggable` is false.

Comment: Add your comments if this is not solution of listed problem.